# Visual Studio 2019 Database Project, How to Refresh/Regenerate

Tags: visual-studio-2019, database-project

I have Visual studio 2019 database Project which has gone out of sync, because of direct updates on the DB.
How do I refresh my visual Studio 2019 Database Project from Source Database ? Did not any option to Refresh/Regenerate.

Comment: In what way has it gone out of sync? What specific errors do you get, in what code?

Comment: New table, function and sequence were added via SSMS, i don't see those new object in my Visual Studio database project

Answer (score 3):

There's a "Schema Compare" command under the Tools Menu -> "SQL Server" -> "New Schema Comparison".  Use that to compare your live database (source) against your project.  I'd suggest that you use the options to ignore things that don't matter to you.  I'll typically ignore users, permissions, comments, whitespace, and such, but you do get a little choice of what to pull over from the results.  Just be careful that what you pull over doesn't overwrite changes you want to keep. You may have to do some manual editing for those cases.