# Converting from EF 6 to EF Core, existing query throwing "given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm in the process of converting one of our .NET Framework applications from EF 6 to EF Core (3.1.26). One of our queries is now throwing a `KeyNotFoundException`.

The query in question is shown here:

```
var data = context.Applications
    .Select(a => new
    {
        a.Id,
        Attempt = a.Attempts
            .Select(fa => new
            {
                fa.CandidateSubmissionReceivedDateUtc,
                fa.FingerprintScores
            })
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == request.ApplicationId);
```

If I remove `fa.FingerprintScores` the query executes fine. With that property in the result set the query throws the `KeyNotFoundException`. It is a collection property on the `Attempts` entity and is defined as follows:

```
private List<FingerprintScore> _fingerprintScores;

public List<FingerprintScore> FingerprintScores =>
    _fingerprintScores = _fingerprintScores ?? new List<FingerprintScore>();
```

Using SQL Server Profiler never shows the request hitting the database so I'm assuming it's blowing up trying to build the expression tree and not something related to the data it's trying to retrieve.

For now I've resolved the issue by doing a second query to get the score information, but we do this sort of thing throughout the codebase so I'd like to have a better idea of what's going wrong.

**UPDATE**

Using LINQPad to try out different combinations I discovered that removing *either* the `fa.FingerprintScores` *or* the `.FirstOrDefault()` causes the query to work. I can reproduce that behavior consistently in any queries that have the same type of relationships.

As someone asked in the comments, here is the stack trace.

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ShaperRemappingExpressionVisitor.GetProjectionIndex(ProjectionBindingExpression projectionBindingExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ShaperRemappingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.CollectionShaperExpression.VisitChildren(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ShaperRemappingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression newExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   at LINQPad.UI.ExplorerGrid.ConvertToList(IEnumerable source)
   at LINQPad.UI.ExplorerGrid.UpdateDataSourceToUse()
```

Comment: Check database and see which columns are set to Primary Key.  You have a context so there is a edmx mapping file which maps the database columns to the c# classes.  There is something wrong with the mapping.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65426440/visual-studio-2019-database-project-how-to-refresh-regenerate

Comment: What's the stack trace of the `KeyNotFoundException`? That would tell us if it's a problem with the query compiler. Why ef core 3.1 (which is EOL in Dec) and not 5+?

Comment: Is `FingerprintScores` property mapped as navigation property (with fluent API)? Because by default EFC does not map get-only properties, and then they cannot be used in queries.

Comment: @jdweng, we do not have an EDMX.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, as mentioned in the first line of my post, the application is still .NET Framework (4.8 to be precise). EF Core 3.1.26 is the most recent version that will support .NET Framework.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I don't believe your statement is correct. We have other properties that are declared the same way and used in similar queries that work. EFC will use the backing property automatically if certain rules are followed so you don't need a setter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field

Comment: @CraigW, maybe just try? I have query that may work, but if Ivan has right, it is not needed.

Comment: @CraigW. I'm just asking because that's the only logical reason I can think of for getting such error. Please note the link you are referring to says *"Note that backing fields are **only** discovered for properties that **are included** in the model."* followed by a link to *Included and excluded properties* topic which starts with *"By convention, all public properties with a getter **and a setter** will be included in the model."*

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, added a setter to the property, same behavior.

Comment: After trying several more things I discovered some new information. I have updated the question.

Comment: How does your Application entity model look like? And also Attempt model

Comment: EFCore was a complete rewrite and there are a number of things not implemented te same way. Thus "upgrading" is not trivial. Best way is to keep things simple and as described in the EFCode guidelines.

Comment: EDMX is not a tool.  It is the extension of a file VS outputs when you are connected to a datasource.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18812 Fixed in 5.0 (stack traces are often useful for finding bug reports)

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, thank you. I had been searching the repo for issues but obviously hadn't used the correct combination of keywords to locate that post.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query. It forces EF Core to use different translation algorithm but give the same result.

```cs
var query = 
    from a in context.Applications
    from fa in a.Attempts
        .Select(fa => new
        {
            fa.CandidateSubmissionReceivedDateUtc,
            fa.FingerprintScores
        })
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        a.Id,
        Attempt = fa
    };    

var data = query
    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == request.ApplicationId);
```

Comment: I would wrap this workaraound in a separate class labelled "TODO:Remove when upgrading to EFCore5!!"

Comment: Why workaround, it is the same query ;)